# VBA Cell location reference with 2 variables

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to select a range using 2 different variables. I know how to do it with 1 variable `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S" & k)` but I'd like to make the range go from $A & j to $S & k and I'm unsure of the proper syntax for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or you can use 'cells' with numbers instead of usung letters and concatenation:

```
Sub SelectRangeUsingCells()
Dim j As Long, k As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ActiveSheet   'ws will be active worksheet
  j = 2                  'example 2. row
  k = 5                  'example 5. row

  With ws
    .Range(.Cells(j, 1), .Cells(k, 19)).Select  'selection of range
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The address is just a string that is concatenated together:

```
"A" & j & ":S" & k
```

So

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & j & ":S" & k)
```

Comment: Yes! It was that extra & that I was missing. Thanks so much.

Comment: Nooo. Don't do string math. Better use `Range(Range("A1").Cell(j,1),Range("S1").Cell(k,1))` or better yet, use relative addressing `Range("A1").Offset(j-1,0).Resize(k-j+1,19)`. The _OP_ may not know better, but someone with 70k reputation should demostrate best practices in answers.

Comment: @ja72 if you are going to use Cells(), better to use sbn's answer below.  And it will be quicker than mine, I just answered the question.  sbn's answer is the best and quickest.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do want you are doing. Let's say you want to pick items 5, 6 and 7 from the example below.

[image: ex1]

```
Public Sub TableSelectionDemo()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    i = 5: j = 7 ' Range of rows for selection

    Set r = Range("E" & i + 7 & ":H" & j + 7)
    Debug.Print r.Address

    Set r = Range(Range("E8").Cells(i, 1), Range("H8").Cells(j, 1))
    Debug.Print r.Address

    Set r = Range("E7").Offset(i, 0).Resize(j - i + 1, 4)
    Debug.Print r.Address


End Sub
```

All three ways produce the same range address: `$E$12:$H$14`.

Now consider what you can do with this range. Consider creating an array in memory and accessing the contents of the range using array operations. For example:

```
Dim vals() As Variant
vals = r.Value      ' Read table values into memory

Dim total_cost As Single
total_cost = 0!

For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count
    ' Multiply 3rd column with 4th column
    total_cost = total_cost + vals(i, 3) * vals(i, 4)
Next i

Debug.Print "Total Cost=" & total_cost
```

This type of operation is extremely fast because, a) It uses floating point math, b) It does not convert from strings to values and back, c) it does not update the screen and d) it does not use the clipboard.